# How set image into ImageView using Glide and a URI?

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I'm trying to display an image in a ImageView using Glide library, the image is in res > drawable folder, and its name retrived from a db. How can I get a resource using an Uri?, `redWifi.getImagen()` returns a string like "imagename.png".

I'm using the next code but doesn't show the image.

```
Glide.with(detallesRedGuardadaActivity.this)
                .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/" + redWifi.getImagen()))
                .asBitmap()
                .into(iconoRed);
```

I tried with `.load(Uri.parse("file://android_asset/" + redWifi.getImagen()))` but still not working.

Comment: you dont need a library to set an image from assets. The easiest thing to do is transfer the image into the drawable folder and then use the `myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_from_drawable);`

Comment: I'm using glide because this code is part of an cursorAdapter and each Item has a image taken from a db, using myImageview.setImageResource, blocks the ui thread due the hight number of items.

Comment: so the image name is in the database and you want to get the proper image  each time based on the image name that it gets from the database right?

Comment: Yep, that's right, the image is in res>drawable>img1.png, in need a proper way to get the reference to a image using the uri  (or other way).

Comment: did you try to perform the setImageResource inside of an AsyncTask? I am not sure it is the proper way but it runs on the background and it will not block the UI thread.

Comment: As you said in your question that images are in drawable folder then you can use it as the code given
below
Glide.with(detallesRedGuardadaActivity.this)
    .load(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage))
                .asBitmap()
                .into(iconoRed);

Comment: I tried save the ID from an image in the db (R.drawable.img) and works well, but if I add other drawable resource to the project, the img showed in the CursorAdapter is not what is soppose to be, that's because the ID saved in the db don't match with the id given by the IDE.

Comment: You can obtain references to resource integers dynamically using one of the techniques described here: https://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The URL `file:///android_asset/` means that you are pointing to `assets` folder in your project. If you don't know where to put this directory, take a look at the Project structure with Gradle [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure).

After that put your images in that folder, and then this should work:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+fileName))
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you!, I moved my pics to assets folder and it worked.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you can accept my answer.

Comment: do i directly pass this to .`load(/storage/emulated/0/1586779115967.jpg)` ?

Comment: I am getting this error ```E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: file:/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/pakage_name/folder_name/image.jpg```